# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' when connecting to redis cluster

Tags: node.js, npm, redis

Below is the code provided in the redis enterprise to connect to their DB.

index.js

```
import { createCluster } from 'redis';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const cluster = createCluster({
    rootNodes: [{
            url: 'rediss://redis.cloud.com:6379'
            }],
    defaults: {
            password: 'abc',
        socket: {
        tls: true,
            ca: [readFileSync('~/redis_ca.pem')]
        }}});
```

Below is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "redis-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "redis-demo.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "run": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "redis": "^4.6.7"
  }
}
```

When I run this code using command `node index.js`  I get below error -

> $ node index.js
>
> /home/rnatarajan/node-redis-demo/node_modules/redis/dist/index.js:42
>
> ```
>        ...options?.modules
>
>                   ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
>
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
>
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
>
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
>
> at ModuleWrap. (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:188:29)
>
> at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:145:37)
>
> at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
>
> at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)

How can I fix this error?

node version -

```
$ node --version
v12.22.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need latest version of node.
upgrade to node v18.3.0 solved the issue.